# Personal budget forecast/tracking solution

Tags: software, budget, cash-flow

I am using mint.com for tracking my money, and it works quite well, with one exception: mint.com is mostly backward-looking, i.e. it captures only stuff that already happened. So I am looking for a good software to allow me to track and predict future expenses - mainly for the purpose of cash flow tracking.

Right now I'm using an excel spreadsheet where I put my expected expenses (credit card payments, loan payments, rent, checks written, savings, etc.) and see what's my projection for this months for the cash flow, how much money I'd have by the end of the month, what happens if I have unexpected expense, etc. This works reasonably well, except for two downsides: it requires some manual work to update and it has no memory - i.e., I can't see how that went over time. It's a bit different snapshot than what Mint has, for example.

So does anybody know of a tool that allows to do the same, but in more convenient way than an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 6):

[You Need A Budget](http://youneedabudget.com/) may be what you're looking for. It is focused on budgeting your expenses in advance, and looking forward instead of backward.

(Disclosure: I am currently doing some development work for You Need A Budget.)

Comment: YNAB is great, but it takes a different approach, having you organize your finances in a way that you don't care about your account balance.

Answer (score 2):

Quicken. I am in the same situation. I've tried mint.com and switched back to Quicken because i want to know how much money i'll have in my accounts in 2 weeks, 4 weeks, etc.

I have to admit though, quicken is getting worse and worse every year. Can't really say i "recommend" it.

Comment: I don't like it any less than I used to, but I don't use the new features, so I recommend it, but do not upgrade more than every three years so it can connect to your bank and download transactions.

Comment: I was forced to update this year, because it said automated downloads will stop working on April 27. Once i upgraded, all citibank accounts failed to connect and i had to setup them up all over again. Maybe it's citibank's fault, i just wish i didn't have to do it. As for new features, i agree, i only use 10% of features. All I really care about is future transactions, reminders and bank downloads.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but for others who may be wondering the same thing, Kualto.com does precisely this. You enter your expected expenses/income and it shows you the beginning and ending balance of each week. You can navigate ahead as much as you want to see how expenses today will affect your account balance in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Personal Finance & Money! Welcome to Personal Finance & Money! Do you have any affiliation with kualto.com? If so please edit your answer to disclose it.